# Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql

Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge The symbol "declare" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to continue.

```
PROCEDURE GETS_SO_ATS_INVALID_NOTIFY AS
  FLAG VARCHAR2(100);
  TRAMS_TOTAL_HOURS NUMBER(4);
  ATS_TOTAL_HOURS NUMBER(4);
  INVALID_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(100);

  BEGIN
     DECLARE
   cursor TRAMS_CURSOR is
   SELECT DISTINCT EMPLY_ID, FISCAL_YEAR, FISCAL_WEEK  , DATE_ENTERED FROM GETS_SO_ATS_TRAMS_NEW_VIEW
   where FISCAL_WEEK <>LNCURRENTFW 
   ;

   BEGIN
   FOR trams_record IN TRAMS_CURSOR LOOP
   TRAMS_TOTAL_HOURS := 0;
   ATS_TOTAL_HOURS := 0;

   END LOOP;

  END;

    PROCEDURE TRAMS_LAB_HOURs_UPLOAD AS
    LSMAILBODY             CLOB;
    LSTOMAIL               VARCHAR2(200);
    LSMAILCC               VARCHAR2(50);
    LSSUBJECT              VARCHAR2(100);
    V_MAIL_ERROR           VARCHAR2(100);
    PNOUTFORECASTID            VARCHAR2(38);
    counter                     number(10);

     BEGIN
     counter:=1;
      PNOUTFORECASTID:='mayank';
      LSSUBJECT:='hello';
      LSMAILBODY := '';

      LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY ||
                    '<HTML><BODY ><FONT FACE=times roman SIZE=3>';
 LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY ||'<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">EMPLOY</th>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">TRAMS</th>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">ATS</th>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">REASON</th>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</tr>';
  FOR counter IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<tr>';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
  LSMAILBODY :=  LSMAILBODY || counter;
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
  LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td></tr>';

END LOOP;
 LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</table>';
      LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</BODY></HTML>';
    LSTOMAIL :='mayank.gandhi@ge.com';
     V_MAIL_ERROR:='hello';
        LSMAILCC:='hello';

    ats_multi_email_clob(LSTOMAIL, LSSUBJECT, LSMAILBODY, LSMAILCC, V_MAIL_ERROR);


    END;




END GETS_SO_ATS_TRAMS_PKG;
```

Comment: You are missing *action* keyword(s). For example, `CREATE OR REPLACE`.  See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php or anything else on Oracle stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Syntax..
First of all You have to define package and then Procedures inside it.
Also for every begin block there should be an 'END' needed.

e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Pkg_test
PROCEDURE Proc_test(
  )
IS
BEGIN
  .... ..
END;
END Proc_test;
END Pkg_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the entire package specification and body. You can try like this without using package.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETS_SO_ATS_INVALID_NOTIFY
AS
  FLAG              VARCHAR2(100);
  TRAMS_TOTAL_HOURS NUMBER(4);
  ATS_TOTAL_HOURS   NUMBER(4);
  INVALID_MESSAGE   VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    CURSOR TRAMS_CURSOR
    IS
      SELECT DISTINCT EMPLY_ID,
        FISCAL_YEAR,
        FISCAL_WEEK ,
        DATE_ENTERED
      FROM GETS_SO_ATS_TRAMS_NEW_VIEW
      WHERE FISCAL_WEEK <>LNCURRENTFW ;
  BEGIN
    FOR trams_record IN TRAMS_CURSOR
    LOOP
      TRAMS_TOTAL_HOURS := 0;
      ATS_TOTAL_HOURS   := 0;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  /
CREATE PROCEDURE TRAMS_LAB_HOURs_UPLOAD
AS
  LSMAILBODY CLOB;
  LSTOMAIL        VARCHAR2(200);
  LSMAILCC        VARCHAR2(50);
  LSSUBJECT       VARCHAR2(100);
  V_MAIL_ERROR    VARCHAR2(100);
  PNOUTFORECASTID VARCHAR2(38);
  counter         NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
  counter        :=1;
  PNOUTFORECASTID:='mayank';
  LSSUBJECT      :='hello';
  LSMAILBODY     := '';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '<HTML><BODY ><FONT FACE=times roman SIZE=3>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY ||'<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">EMPLOY</th>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">TRAMS</th>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">ATS</th>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '<th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;background-color:#ffcb2f;color:#010066">REASON</th>';
  LSMAILBODY     := LSMAILBODY || '</tr>';
  FOR counter IN 1 .. 5
  LOOP
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<tr>';
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '<td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal">';
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || counter;
    LSMAILBODY := LSMAILBODY || '</td></tr>';
  END LOOP;
  LSMAILBODY  := LSMAILBODY || '</table>';
  LSMAILBODY  := LSMAILBODY || '</BODY></HTML>';
  LSTOMAIL    :='mayank.gandhi@ge.com';
  V_MAIL_ERROR:='hello';
  LSMAILCC    :='hello';
  ats_multi_email_clob(LSTOMAIL, LSSUBJECT, LSMAILBODY, LSMAILCC, V_MAIL_ERROR);
END;
/
```